# botboox confirm dialog dont wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I'm using bootbox to confirm a user action.

I have a button that submits a form, and when that button is clicked I need the user's confirmation to submit or cancel:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(btn_continue).click(function(){

        bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result){
            if (result) {
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
});
```

the problem is popup appears then disappear without waiting for the user click!
Please why this happens?

Comment: Please post a working fiddle in order to reproduce your issue...

Comment: Hi @Hackerman, I add that *btn_continue* is a submit button. I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it removing your `else` and using type button in your `#btn_continue`:

```
$("#btn_continue").click(function(e) {
    bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result){
      if (result) {
        $("#form").submit();
      }
    });
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0h7fer7/

Explanation:
The bootbox is closing because you are posting your form before it. The click event handler ends before the result of `bootbox.confirm`, and allow your button `type="submit"` to post your form. `bootbox.confirm` is an assynchonus call.

Comment: @abdoBim I added a name and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/v0h7fer7/1/

Comment: it did not work for me because I have 2 buttons with same name. so I changed the name of one. Thanks :)